# Steps for packaging Android source code into an app for phone?

Tags: android

I just want to test this on my phone and not clear at all how to go about that

https://github.com/kai-morich/SimpleBluetoothTerminal

Comment: Did this not work? https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device

Comment: Got it to work now yes. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the code (green button Clone or download -> Download ZIP), then unpack ZIP, open the app in Android Studio and run on your phone.